# Ebizmarts Magento Checkout Error - Multi Store

Tags: magento, opayo

Having some issues with website2 on a multi store setup - this is a new website, website1 is working perfectly, and have recently set up website2 which is working, until we go to the payment gateway (Sagepay) using the Ebizmarts plugin.

When its supposed to redirect to the SagePay server, it throws an exception with the following error code:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:35:"Unable to initialize FORM Checkout.";i:1;s:1098:"#0 /home/website/public_html/app/code/local/Ebizmarts/SagePaySuite/controllers/FormPaymentController.php(74): Mage::throwException('Unable to initi...')
#1 /home/website/public_html/app/code/local/Ebizmarts/SagePaySuite/controllers/FormPaymentController.php(105): Ebizmarts_SagePaySuite_FormPaymentController->_initCheckout()
#2 /home/website/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Ebizmarts_SagePaySuite_FormPaymentController->goAction()
#3 /home/website/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('go')
#4 /home/website/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#5 /home/website/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#6 /home/website/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /home/website/public_html/index.php(103): Mage::run('retail_default', 'store')
#8 {main}";s:3:"url";s:68:"/index.php/sgps/formPayment/go/?SID=c9f79e48a26b52cbcb91414d43c27595";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:14:"retail_default";}
```

I have checked everywhere, an I'm unable to find what can be causing the issue...

The only way i can get it to work is when going to website1, go to the checkout process and proceed to sagepay - i can then cancel the transaction, go to website2 and proceed to checkout... I am then redirected to SagePay, but i have my transaction from website1 in Sage...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: I found the issue - it was due to a typo.